# testing if PrimedTnt exists in a block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make better looking explosions in minecraft. I use this command to detect PrimedTnt where the explosion happens (x=-272 y=58 z=-1844)

> testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt] [x=-272 y=58 z=-1844]

But it gives me this error message:

> [20:48:37] Data tag parsing failed: Invalid tag encountered, expected '{' as first char.

Why does this happen? Also, what can I do about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using selectors, all of the arguments go between the same pair of square brackets and are separated by commas. What you wanted to do is probably this:

```
testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt,x=-272,y=58,z=-1844]
```

You're getting the error message because you've made `[x=-272 y=58 z=-1844]` an argument of its own, not part of the selector. As it happens, the second argument for `testfor` is NBT data. The correct **syntax** to specify NBT data would, as the answer above says, be `{x:-272,y:58,z:-1844}`.

**HOWEVER** no entity has an "x" int, a "y" int, and a "z" int in it's data. Although it's the correct syntax and won't cause an error, it will never match an entity. The correct **tags** for specifying location with the NBT argument would be this:

```
testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt] {Pos:[-271.5,58.5,-1843.5]}
```

The chances are you didn't want to do that though, as it'd test only for that very specific point in space and nothing else. The solution is the first command I gave, where all of the arguments are in the square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

The error message already gives you a hint to what is wrong:

```
expected '{' as first char
```

You only have your syntax a little wrong:

```
testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt] {x=-272,y=58,z=-1844}
```

Notice the curly braces and the commas between the coordinates.
But notice, the command above is not very pretty. A more reliable and readable would be as follows:

```
testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt,x=-272,y=58,z=-1844,r=2]
```

This gets rid of the data tag, and can use the radius.

Comment: I will try it tomorrow

Comment: It does work as command (syntax is okay) but the comparetor never gets activated, even when i tried with the radius testfor @e[type=PrimedTnt] {x=-272,y=58,z=-1844,r=2} but then it gave me an error: [14:52:01] Data tag parsing failed: Unable to locate name/value separator for string: x=-272,y=58,z=-1844,r=2

Comment: Colorfusion already answered the question, but I still added a solution to your comment ;)

Comment: thx bro you deserve a 1 up as well

Answer (score 0):

SirBenet's answer is correct in a sense, but not entirely. You must use `tnt` rather than `PrimedTnt.` Also, instead of having the coordinates in curly brackets `{}` they should still be in the brackets next to the item name, separated by a comma. So, what you want to do now is this:

```
@e[type=tnt,x=-272,y=58,z=-1844].
```

Also note, the command will not function without a specified radius, be it 1 or more. So, if you want that block, use `r=1`. For any area specified around that one block (up, down, left, right, diagonally, etc.) use `r=2` or any other number (keep it below 1,000 as it will get very laggy). So, the final command would be this:

```
/testfor @e[type=tnt,x=-272,y=58,z=-1844,r=1].
```

For a full list of the entity names and data values including tnt, visit [The Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entity#Types_of_entities):